# No resource identifier found for attribute 'margin' in package 'android'

Tags: java, android

I started android development 2 days ago and tried building this basic app, but it's been showing this error. I've been at it since 3 hrs but to no avail. Please help !

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b10);
    one.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b15);
    two.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b20);
    three.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.b10:
            display(10);
            break;

        case R.id.b15:
            display(15);
            break;

        case R.id.b20:
            display(20);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
}
```

It's showing the error
Error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'margin' in package 'android'

I have been on it since last 3 hrs, and I cannot find why this error is being caused. I chose API 19, KitKat 4.4 for development based on Statistics. If that is the reason of the problem, please also suggest which one to use in the future.

Comment: what is display(20);  ???

Comment: I made a function. It will setText to a textView element. Should I put it as well ?

Comment: Somewhere in your layout XML, you have an attribute like `android:margin="..."`. There is no `margin` attribute. It's `layout_margin`.